# is there a way to check similarity between two full sentences in python?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, nltk, sentence-similarity

I am making a project like this one here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dovB8uSUUXE&feature=youtu.be
but i am facing trouble because i need to check the similarity between the sentences for example:
if the user said: **'the person wear red T-shirt'** instead of **'the boy wear red T-shirt'**
I want a method to check the similarity between these two sentences without having to check the similarity between each word
is there a way to do this in python?

I am trying to find a way to check the similarity between two sentences.

Comment: see [fuzzywuzzy](https://pypi.org/project/fuzzywuzzy/) you may need to use lemmatization first, depending of your problem

Comment: How do you want to define your similarity, then?

Comment: You might be interested in reading this question / answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62766787/is-there-a-python-library-or-tool-that-analyzes-two-bodies-of-text-for-similarit/64134066#64134066

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you (compare strings based on meaning): https://stackoverflow.com/a/63011600/7080911

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Most of there libraries below should be good choice for semantic similarity comparison. You can skip direct word comparison by generating word, or sentence vectors using pretrained models from these libraries.

### Sentence similarity with `Spacy`

Required models must be loaded first.

For using `en_core_web_md` use `python -m spacy download en_core_web_md` to download. For using `en_core_web_lg` use `python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg`.

The large model is around ~830mb as writing and quite slow, so medium one can be a good choice.

https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity/

**Code:**

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
#nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")


doc1 = nlp(u'the person wear red T-shirt')
doc2 = nlp(u'this person is walking')
doc3 = nlp(u'the boy wear red T-shirt')


print(doc1.similarity(doc2)) 
print(doc1.similarity(doc3))
print(doc2.similarity(doc3))
```

**Output:**

```
0.7003971105290047
0.9671912343259517
0.6121211244876517
```

### Sentence similarity with `Sentence Transformers`

https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers

https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html

Install with `pip install -U sentence-transformers`. This one generates sentence embedding.

**Code:**

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens')

sentences = [
    'the person wear red T-shirt',
    'this person is walking',
    'the boy wear red T-shirt'
    ]
sentence_embeddings = model.encode(sentences)

for sentence, embedding in zip(sentences, sentence_embeddings):
    print("Sentence:", sentence)
    print("Embedding:", embedding)
    print("")
```

**Output:**

```
Sentence: the person wear red T-shirt
Embedding: [ 1.31643847e-01 -4.20616418e-01 ... 8.13076794e-01 -4.64620918e-01]

Sentence: this person is walking
Embedding: [-3.52878094e-01 -5.04286848e-02 ... -2.36091137e-01 -6.77282438e-02]

Sentence: the boy wear red T-shirt
Embedding: [-2.36365378e-01 -8.49713564e-01 ... 1.06414437e+00 -2.70157874e-01]
```

Now embedding vector can be used to calculate various similarity metrics.

**Code:**

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
print(util.pytorch_cos_sim(sentence_embeddings[0], sentence_embeddings[1]))
print(util.pytorch_cos_sim(sentence_embeddings[0], sentence_embeddings[2]))
print(util.pytorch_cos_sim(sentence_embeddings[1], sentence_embeddings[2]))
```

**Output:**

```
tensor([[0.4644]])
tensor([[0.9070]])
tensor([[0.3276]])
```

Same thing with `scipy` and `pytorch`,

**Code:**

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
print(1 - distance.cosine(sentence_embeddings[0], sentence_embeddings[1]))
print(1 - distance.cosine(sentence_embeddings[0], sentence_embeddings[2]))
print(1 - distance.cosine(sentence_embeddings[1], sentence_embeddings[2]))
```

**Output:**

```
0.4643629193305969
0.9069876074790955
0.3275738060474396
```

**Code:**

```
import torch.nn
cos = torch.nn.CosineSimilarity(dim=0, eps=1e-6)
b = torch.from_numpy(sentence_embeddings)
print(cos(b[0], b[1]))
print(cos(b[0], b[2]))
print(cos(b[1], b[2]))
```

**Output:**

```
tensor(0.4644)
tensor(0.9070)
tensor(0.3276)
```

### Sentence similarity with `TFHub Universal Sentence Encoder`

https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/semantic_similarity_with_tf_hub_universal_encoder.ipynb

Model is very large for this one around 1GB and seems slower than others. This also generates embeddings for sentences.

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4")
embeddings = embed([
    "the person wear red T-shirt",
    "this person is walking",
    "the boy wear red T-shirt"
    ])

print(embeddings)
```

**Output:**

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.063188    0.07063895 -0.05998802 ... -0.01409875  0.01863449
   0.01505797]
 [-0.06786212  0.01993554  0.03236153 ...  0.05772103  0.01787272
   0.01740014]
 [ 0.05379306  0.07613157 -0.05256693 ... -0.01256405  0.0213196
  -0.00262441]], shape=(3, 512), dtype=float32)
```

**Code:**

```
from scipy.spatial import distance
print(1 - distance.cosine(embeddings[0], embeddings[1]))
print(1 - distance.cosine(embeddings[0], embeddings[2]))
print(1 - distance.cosine(embeddings[1], embeddings[2]))
```

**Output:**

```
0.15320375561714172
0.8592830896377563
0.09080004692077637
```

### Other Sentence Embedding Libraries

https://github.com/facebookresearch/InferSent

https://github.com/Tiiiger/bert_score

This illustration shows the method,

[image]

### Resources

[How to compute the similarity between two text documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8897593/how-to-compute-the-similarity-between-two-text-documents)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity#Angular_distance_and_similarity

https://towardsdatascience.com/word-distance-between-word-embeddings-cc3e9cf1d632

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cosine.html

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/CosineSimilarity

https://nlp.town/blog/sentence-similarity/

Comment: Thanks for this. Which one is less sensitive to the sentence length? For example, sentence A is a part of sentence B, with only very few different words.

Comment: spacy doc similarity is useless. I don't know what method it implements underneath, but one thing is for sure, it serves no useful purpose.

Comment: Excellent answer, Thank you! 
Quick question how and why did you choose "distilbert-base-nli-mean-tokens" model vs others?

Comment: @AashishChaubey Why is it useless? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

This will be a very simple but very effective approach we implemented in our organization. We are not looking for semantic similarity so used below.

Jaccard - index
https://www.statisticshowto.com/jaccard-index/