# What robust algorithm implementation can I use to perform phrase similarity with two inputs?

Tags: nlp, string-comparison, similarity, sentence-similarity, name-matching

This is the problem:

- I have two columns in my matadata database "field name" and "field description"
- I need to check if the "field description" is actually a description and not some sort of transformation of the "field name"
- **[Edit]** I need to avoid preprocessing the text to remove separators, as I would have to consider a long list of cases (e.g. _-;$%/^| etc.)

Examples:

| row | field_name | field_description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | my_first_field | my first field |
| 2 | my_second_field | my------second------field |
| 3 | my_third_field | this is a description about the field, the descriprion can contain the name of the field itself |

Where the examples 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> are similars (thus wrong) and the 3<sup>rd</sup> is correct.

I have tried some implementations based on Leveinshtein Distance, difflib, Cosine Similarity and an implementation called spaCy but none of them was robust with my examples (throwing only around 50% of similarity rate with the 1<sup>st</sup> example).

Some of the implementations I tried to use:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/surprisingly-effective-way-to-name-matching-in-python-1a67328e670e
- https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#vectors-similarity
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html
- [is there a way to check similarity between two full sentences in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199011/is-there-a-way-to-check-similarity-between-two-full-sentences-in-python)

**[Edit]**

I have just tried the implementation of HuggingFace [semantic-textual-similarity](https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html#semantic-textual-similarity) with nice results.

| field_name | field_description | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| my_field_name | my_field_name | 1.0000 |
| second_field_name | second field name | 0.8483 |
| third_field_name | third-field-name | 0.8717 |
| fourth_field_name | this is a correct description field | 0.4591 |
| fifth_field_name | fifth_-------field_//////////////name | 0.8454 |

Answer (score 2):

For your examples, the [Levenshtein edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) would work very well. It can also be 'customized', or you could use some preprocessing depending on your data.

But your text description of the problem makes me think that the real problem is likely much more complex, and maybe not even easy to define formally. It looks like you actually need a more semantic method, and this would probably require training a model with annotated data.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried Leveinshtein Distance but the problem is: how do you fix a threshold with so many cases?(preprocessing in this case is not useful as the list of cases is too long).

I agree that maybe training a model for such a purpose would be the best option but I wanted to look for other options first.

By the way, I have just tried the implementation of HuggingFace [semantic-textual-similarity](https://www.sbert.net/docs/usage/semantic_textual_similarity.html#semantic-textual-similarity) with nice results.

Comment: @emichester Deciding the threshold can be done in different ways, but the goal is always for the value to separate as well as possible the cases. If you want do it really properly, take a sample of annotated instances and pick the value which maximizes accuracy on this sample (parameter tuning).

Comment: Interesting approach, but, which values should be the inputs of the optimizer? x1,x2,x3 directly?
- x1    : field_name
- x2    : field_description
- x3    : lev distance
- y     : annotation

Or just a simple optimizer with x3 as input?

Comment: @emichester in this simplistic approach there's no need to keep the text values, you use only the numerical distance value. The idea is that the distance represents how much the text differ.