# How to match rows of a dataframe rows to another dataframe row using Python NLP techniques

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I have two data frames (`df1` and `df2`).
`df1` looks something like this:

```
data = [['RJ REYNOLDS VAPOR', 'Tobacco Products', 21, '4442fa51-d4b7-4d56-ad7c-d18cfd2aff84', 'Mature'],
['BEYOND MEAT', 'Packaged Meat', 30, 'e73f7957-0e65-4466-9588-795bdc5f67ac', 'Pantry'],
['BEYOND MEAT', 'Plant-Based Meat', 1584, 'd8cb60e5-b0c6-478a-971d-c6c55b17831f', 'Meat & Seafood'],
['BEYOND MEAT', 'Frozen Plant-Based Meat', 313, '8e0a9431-5462-4810-9f65-68fe36adf454', 'Frozen'],
['TARGET', 'Wine', 39, 'ca1c0f4d-3efc-4978-8357-69862996f416', 'Alcohol'],
['TARGET', 'Deodorant & Antiperspirant', 192, 'ca1c0f4d-3efc-4978-8357-69862996f416', 'Health & Wellness'],
['DOVE', 'Bath & Body', 15821, '47fae368-9b64-40be-82c9-898f953e9d66', 'Health & Wellness']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['BRAND', 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY', 'RECEIPTS', 'CATEGORY_ID', 'PARENT_CATEGORY'])
```

Looks something like this (the original is 9906 x 5):

| BRAND | PRODUCT_CATEGORY | RECEIPTS | CATEGORY_ID | PARENT_CATEGORY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RJ REYNOLDS VAPOR | Tobacco Products | 21 | 4442fa51-d4b7-4d56-ad7c-d18cfd2aff84 | Mature |
| BEYOND MEAT | Packaged Meat | 30 | e73f7957-0e65-4466-9588-795bdc5f67ac | Pantry |
| BEYOND MEAT | Plant-Based Meat | 1584 | d8cb60e5-b0c6-478a-971d-c6c55b17831f | Meat & Seafod |

`df2` looks something like this:

```
offer_data = [['Beyond Meat® Plant-Based products, spend $25', None, 'BEYOND MEAT'],
['Beyond Steak™ Plant-Based seared tips, 10 ounce at Target', 'TARGET', 'BEYOND MEAT'],
['Beyond Steak™ Plant-Based seared tips, 10 ounce at H-E-B', 'H-E-B', 'BEYOND MEAT'],
['Dove Hand Wash select varieties buy 2 at TARGET', 'TARGET', 'DOVE'],
['Dove Hand Wash select varieties at Target', 'TARGET', 'DOVE']]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(offer_data, columns = ['OFFER', 'RETAILER', 'BRAND'])
```

`df2` Original is 384 x 3

| OFFER | RETAILER | BRAND |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Beyond Meat® Plant-Based products, spend $25 | None | BEYOND MEAT |
| Beyond Steak™ Plant-Based seared tips, 10 ounce at Target | TARGET | BEYOND MEAT |

My goal is to add the appropriate 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY', 'PARENT_CATEGORY' and 'CATEGORY_ID' to each offer.

First I removed all non-alphanumeric characters from the 'OFFER" column in `df2`

```
df2['OFFER'] = df2.OFFER.str.replace('[^\w\s]', '')
```

then I extracted keywords from the 'OFFERS' column using the yake library:

```
import yake

offers = df2['OFFER'].unique()

kw_extractor = yake.KeywordExtractor()
language = 'en'
max_ngram_size = 3
deduplication_threshold = 0.9
numOfKeywords = 6
custom_kw_extractor = yake.KeywordExtractor(lan=language, n=max_ngram_size, dedupLim=deduplication_threshold, top=numOfKeywords, features=None)


tags = []
for offer in offers:
    keywords = custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(offer)
    subtags = []
    for kw in keywords:
        subtags.append(kw[0])
        
    tags.append(subtags)
```

Which gave me a list of lists of keywords for each offer. I am pretty new to using NLP, so this is where I am getting stuck. I can match the 'BRAND' in `df1` to the 'BRAND' in `df2` to filter out most of the rows in `df1`. Some offers are only available at specific retailers and all offers belong to a 'PRODUCT'/'PARENT' category. My idea is to use the keywords extracted from the offers and find a closely related row match from `df1`. In the example data frame above some offers can fit into multiple categories like the 'BEYOND MEAT' categories. What is the best way to iterate through both data frames to find the appropriate 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY'/'PARENT_CATEGORY' for each offer? Or would there be an easier (more effective/accurate?) method to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a fairly simple approach close to what you suggested, using the Jaccard similarity, here the ratio of the size of the intersection between the offer kewords and the brand/category keywords to size of the union of the two keyword sets. Each offer simply gets associated whichever brand/category gives the highest Jaccard index (i.e. the columns `['PRODUCT_CATEGORY', 'PARENT_CATEGORY', 'CATEGORY_ID']` are added to `df2`).

```
import pandas as pd

#data = ...
#offer_data = ...

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['BRAND', 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY', 'RECEIPTS', 'CATEGORY_ID', 'PARENT_CATEGORY'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(offer_data, columns=['OFFER', 'RETAILER', 'BRAND'])

df1.fillna('', inplace=True)
df2.fillna('', inplace=True)

def keywords(x):
    return set(' '.join(x).lower().split(' '))

def similarity(a, b):
    if len(a) == 0 or len(b) == 0:
        return 0
    return len(a & b) / len(a | b)

df1_kws = df1[['BRAND', 'PRODUCT_CATEGORY', 'PARENT_CATEGORY']].apply(keywords, axis=1)
identifier = df1[['PRODUCT_CATEGORY', 'PARENT_CATEGORY', 'CATEGORY_ID']].values

res = []
for offer_kws in df2[['OFFER', 'RETAILER', 'BRAND']].apply(f, axis=1):
    best_sim = -1
    best = None
    for idx, kws in zip(identifier, df1_kws):
        sim = similarity(offer_kws, kws)
        if sim > best_sim:
            best = idx
            best_sim = sim
    res.append(best)

df2[['PRODUCT_CATEGORY', 'PARENT_CATEGORY', 'CATEGORY_ID']] = res
```

Note that this does not work well as is and is mainly meant for demonstration purposes. Of course one could attempt to improve the keyword extraction from the dataframe rows (see `keywords`) or tweak the definition of the similarity measure (see `similarity`), or in other ways build in some custom logic to the selection process. However, I feel an approach that may be very appropriate here is an encoder that maps a sentence (e.g. sequence of keywords or even mere concatenation of the strings in the relevant dataframe columns) to an embedding vector. Oftentimes, e.g. cosine similarity between such vector nicely approximates semantic similarity. I can only recommend to have a look at [this nice overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65199011/is-there-a-way-to-check-similarity-between-two-full-sentences-in-python) about sentence similarity.